# SICP video seems easier than the book

Tags: sicp

I find video lectures on SICP easier than the book. Is it really so? Have they got the same material? What is the optimal way of combining both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SICP videos](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) are 20 lectures of ca. 60 minute lectures and covers the main essence of the book but far from all. This makes the videos easier to understand and in addition many gets things better by getting several senses stimulated at the same time which videos does. If you have your REPL ready and try stuff it's even better.

I usually link to the video lecture rather than the book when something coevered in the lectures are asked about. I love watching the wizards myself :)

I don't know how to combine them, but I've seen all the videos and started with the book afterwards to read and do the exercises, which I'm not yet finished with.